# Reading the type of a variable from a file

Tags: c++, file, struct

I've come across a problem and have zero idea how to come about it. After a couple of days of searching for an answer I decided to make my own thread. 
I'm trying to create a simple data base with a structure of data dictated by a configuration file. Let me give an example:
The program initially has a structure of a couple of strings:

```
struct Data
{
    string name, surname, id;
};
```

The config file:

```
VAR NAME   TYPE     MAX LENGTH 
NAME       STRING     30
SURNAME    STRING     30
ID         INT        10
```

The program is supposed to open the file and then check the type of variables and if needed change the struct Data accordingly, or create a new one. The part of opening the file and navigating in it is easy, but I have no clue how to check the types.
I really hope I described the problem clearly.
Thanks for any hints!

Comment: not trying to be snarky, but the simple solution is to store all data as strings, and only convert them when needed, did you consider that? In any case, how do you intend to use the struct in your code? The caller needs to know what type eg `Id` is to do anything with it

Comment: It's just a simple pogram for the training sake. The ID is a way to find the element within the data base if there's a need for editing or deleting it. 
I've played around with the thought of converting the strings into the according types, but later on I want to expand on the idea and not constrain myself with a set number of variables. The goal is to create a fully modifiable data base. So if I add a new var into the file, the program is to identify the change and make a new variable within the code. Is it possible?

Comment: @ReeD: The config file contains the schema. How do you feed the data?

Comment: If possible why don't you use `json` or `xml` as the file format. Then it will be super easy to parse the content [using some libraries] and process accordingly. It will also be easy to impose your schema with these file formats. Reading and parsing from normal text file is not very difficult but it comes with it's own overhead.

Comment: @Sitesh 
Unfortunately I'm forced to use .txt extention. If it's not too much of a problem, could you please point me in the general direction that I should take?

Comment: @ReeD: The extension could be `.txt` and you can still store whatever format you decide to choose. You can choose JSON or some other format if the format is not a hard requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Store the data as strings. Implement a way for the program to convert strings to the data you need. You can convert [string to integers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/), [doubles](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stod/?kw=stod), or [floats](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stof/) for example.